# nginx reverse proxy upstream fails in docker-compose with connection refused message

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` similar to this (shortened for simplicity):

```
# ...
services:
  my-ui:
    # ...
    ports:
    - 5402:8080
  networks:
  - my-net

networks:
  my-net:
    external:
      name: my-net
```

and I'm trying to set up `nginx` as a reverse proxy with this configuration:

```
upstream client {
  server my-ui:5402;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }
}
```

and this is the `docker-compose.yaml` I have for `nginx`:

```
# ...
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # ...
    ports:
    - 5500:80
    networks:
    - my-net

networks:
  my-net:
    external:
      name: my-net
```

What happens now is that when I run `my-ui` and `reverse-proxy` (each using its own `docker-compose up`), and I go to `http://localhost:5500`, I get a `Bad Gateway` message, and my `nginx` logs says this:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to 
upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://172.19.0.5:5402/", host: "localhost:5500"
```

If I `exec` into my `nginx` container and use `ping`:

```
ping my-ui
ping 172.19.0.5
```

Both are successful, but if I want to, for example, `curl`:

```
curl -L http://my-ui
curl -L http://my-ui:5402
curl -L http://172.19.0.1
```

All of them fail with `connection refused` message. What am I missing here?

PS: I'm not sure, but it might be useful to add that `my-ui` is a basic `vuejs` application, running on Webpack dev server.

PS2: I also tried passing host headers etc. but same result

Comment: Have you tried server my-ui:8080 in your nginx config?

Comment: Thank you so much @Mathias, I wasted 2:30 hours last night, trying to make it work, but I had no idea that I needed to go to the actual port in the container, and not the one I map in docker-compose. Could you explain why's that the case? And maybe, if you want, you can do that as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: You are welcome. Great to hear it's working now. This are the small detail that cost you most of the time. I added an answer. Let me know in case you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the container (`my-ui`) resolves to the IP of the container. Therefor you have to provide in upstream the port of the container and not the port you have mapped to the host.

```
upstream client {
  server my-ui:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }
}
```

You could also configure your upstream with the name of your host machine and use the mapped port. (`server <name of host>:5402`) But this could get quite messy and you would lose the advantage of isolating services with docker networks.

Furthermore you could also remove the port mapping unless you need to access the webservice without reverse proxy:

```
# ...
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # ...
    # ports:
    # - 5500:80
```